# HDFS default block size is 128 MB while Hive default stripe size is 250 MB

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, bigdata

HDFS block size is 128 MB by default (source: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)

Hive stripe size is 250 MB by default (source: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC#LanguageManualORC-FileStructure)

And to my understanding, 1 stripe must fit entirely within 1 block in HDFS.

Am I missing something here? Do I have the incorrect information?

would you simply just need to configure HDFS to have 250 MB blocks in order to fit the stripes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orc file format is splittable at stripe level.  That means it's not required to fit one stripe size into one block.

HDFS block size is at the file level, regardless of its format.

Comment: So one stripe can be stored on 2 or more HDFS blocks?